# OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy - when running code in virtual env

Tags: python, virtualenv

The following code:

```
if os.path.exists(discarded_ims_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(discarded_ims_dir) 
    os.makedirs(discarded_ims_dir)
```

Gives the following error when running it in a virtual environment on ubuntu 18.04. (I run ubuntu 18.04 in a virtual machine on windows 10.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "select_images.py", line 93, in <module>
   main()
   File "select_images.py", line 37, in main
   shutil.rmtree(discarded_ims_dir) 
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 490, in rmtree
   onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 488, in rmtree
   os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy: '/home/johan/HagelJo/ladle_id_ims_3-17-2020_discarded'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Text file busy obviously means the file is being used by another application. Are you positive it's not being used by another application (like one you wrote or another instance of your program)?

Comment: It is not being used. This happens when I activate a virtual env and runs the script. II does not happen when i run the script in the vscode debugger.